# jQuery read text file in reverse order

Tags: jquery, file, text, reverse, array-reverse

I was using this php line to make the magic happens :

```
$contents = array_reverse(explode("\n", $contents));
```

I was wondering how to do the same magic in jQuery.

This is the line without reverse :

```
function(){$('#myDiv').load('textfile.txt').fadeIn("slow");}
```

Thanks !

Comment: I am sure someone else may post a clever way to do this in pure jQuery, but a simple solution would be just retrieve the value via AJAX from a PHP page.

Comment: I'm looking for the cleanest way. just to explode \n and reverse the order or even a cleaner method.